# Flyway alpha caracters in version number

Tags: flyway

With Flyway 2.1, the use of alpha caracters in version number is no longer supported, can somebody explain why this has been dropped?
We have to rename all our SQL scripts and conf files, pain in the ass but ok doable...
But what should we do with the metadata table?

Grrrrr ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The support was undocumented and I simply hadn't seen anyone using it.

Feel free to file an enhancement request in the issue tracker with the specific types of version strings you need.